# Slow PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, performance, soap-client

I'm using a webservice through PHP soapclient class and at one point i call this function:

```
$response = $client->CompanySearch($callParams);
```

But it's very slow, so I've done this to try to monitor it:

```
$time1=time();
$response = $client->CompanySearch($callParams);
$time2=time();
$this->LastExecTime=$time2-$time1;
```

and I get times of about 7-9 seconds where the webservice admin did some monitoring on his side and he says it's only about 4 seconds (sometimes 6) so where are all the extra seconds coming from? Is this php function particularly slow? I only timed the call to the soapclient method CompanySearch without timing everything else I do in my code in fear that somehting else was slowing it down. Any ideas? Any quicker alternaties to the SoapClient php class? Is the webservice admin not quite monitoring right?

At first I though he was just giving me DB query times but he says his times are complete with the XML parsing and then forming.

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: `only about 4 seconds` - and the webservice admin is happy with that? :-S A "particularly slow" PHP function is a matter of a couple of extra milliseconds, not seconds. Total stab in the dark, but you should check your server's DNS lookup server/cache speed. But if the web service is taking a matter of seconds process requests, I would guess that the problem is at the other end.

Comment: I don't think it's my DNS because otherwise this would be slow too: $client = new SoapClient($this->url_generic, $params); that's when i read the wsdl... Yes 4 secs is a lot but bettere thatn 7-9

Comment: In that case you should try mimicking the HTTP requests directly and seeing how long they take. You can do this either in PHP using things like cURL, or using a browser tool like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/). If the HTTP request itself takes the 7-9 seconds, you know the problem is with the server's request processing. If it takes the prescribed 4-6 seconds, you know you have a problem internally with the SOAPClient's processing. To me it seems like that the remote admin's benchmark is not telling them the full story.

Comment: hmmm... poster requires the same time... I'm going to email the webservice admin and see if I can get him to time a call from the internet to see for himself.. Giving me his internal times doesn't make sense..

Comment: ok ended up trying a similar service still through SOAP with another supplier and is under a second now :) thanks for everything! I can tick your comment if you put it as a reply.